# Взаимодействие Sklearn и Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Задача - регрессии через метод К_соседей. 
Имею образцовый рабочий код:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor as KNR

kf=KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 42) 

estimator = KNR(metric='minkowski', n_neighbors=5, weights='distance') 

results = cross_val_score(estimator=estimator, X=data, y=target, cv=kf, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

results
```

В результате получаю некоторый массив данных.

Повторяю код с уточнением метрик:

```
for k in numpy.linspace(1, 10, num=200):

    estimator = KNR(metric='minkowski', n_neighbors=k, weights='distance')
    results = cross_val_score(estimator=estimator, X=data, y=target, cv=kf, 
    scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
    results
```

И натыкаюсь на несовпадение типов входных данных для K (`numpy.linspace` - `float`) и `n_neighbors=k` (`sklearn` - `int`).

> ```
> TypeError: n_neighbors does not take <class 'numpy.float64'> value, enter integer value
> ```

А как задавать `float` под требования `int`?

Понятно, что никак. Но условия задачи предполагают, что я используя команду `linspace`, это сделаю.

Comment: Извините, что беспокою вас. Я искал Евгения_Венева и увидел его проблему на другом сайте. Но я не могу зарегистрироваться на другом сайте. Название сайта “quasar”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.linspace()` - возвращает массив вещественных чисел.

Число соседей в алгоритме KNN не может быть вещественным / нецелым числом.

Попробуйте так:

```
for k in [3,5,7]:
    estimator = KNR(metric='minkowski', n_neighbors=k, weights='distance')
    ....
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> условие задачи: Переберите разные варианты параметра метрики p по
>   сетке от 1 до 10 с таким шагом, чтобы всего было протестировано 200
>   вариантов (используйте функцию `numpy.linspace`)

```
for p in np.linspace(1, 100, 200):
    estimator = KNR(metric='minkowski', weights='distance', p=p)
```